# Installing a repo not in PyPI

Tags: python, git, pip

This is my first time trying to install a repo not in PyPI. I'm not sure if I'm having a general issue or a specific issue with the package.

Repo:
https://github.com/jeslago/epftoolbox

Instructions are:

```
git clone https://github.com/jeslago/epftoolbox.git

cd epftoolbox
```

Then, simply install the library using pip:

```
pip install .
```

I've tried several approaches.

I tried adding the repo in Pycharm, as "https://github.com/jeslago/epftoolbox.git/" in the settings.

I tried using pip install from a local version of the repo

```
python -m pip install C:\Users\user\epftoolbox\
```

I tried installing in anaconda

```
git clone https://github.com/jeslago/epftoolbox.git
cd epftoolbox
pip install .
```

I get this error

```
Successfully built epftoolbox termcolor
ERROR: tensorflow 2.3.0 has requirement scipy==1.4.1, but you'll have scipy 1.5.2 which is incompatible.
```

But it finishes with "Successfully installed epftoolbox-1.0"

The issue is that I can do "import epftoolbox"

Fine. But if I try and run a script with "from epftoolbox.data import read_data"

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'epftoolbox.data'
```

So I take it that the package didn't actually install?

I'm not sure what to try next?

I've python 3.8.5 installed 64 bit.
I've get the same issue in pycharm and idle.

Comment: `pip install scipy==1.4.1`

Comment: I think the package already did that

Found existing installation: scipy 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to install specific version of scipy to work with this library, try to uninstall current version and then install the correct version with this commands:

```
python -m uninstall scipy
python -m install -Iv scipy==1.4.1
```

Comment: I had a look at that, 

Found existing installation: scipy 1.4.1